# Уничтожить Window после завершения потока

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Есть метод `Something` я его запускаю 100500 раз, однако объект `System.Windows.Window` не исчезает из памяти.

```
private void Something()
{
  Thread t = new Thread(()=> {
    Window w = new Window() { Width = 1024, Height = 768 };
    w.Show();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    w.Close();
  });
  t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
  t.Start();
  GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/c5425651-2294-4b99-bc32-7a1fe88e4b03/-wpf?forum=fordesktopru вот тут есть очень полезная инфа по освобождению ресурсов окна..

Comment: @Mr.Modest в статье ответа не нашел кроме "не парься за 20 метров", но у меня гиг выжерает, и чем дальше тем больше

Comment: Попробуйте создать свой класс, который будет наследоваться от Window и реализовывать IDisposable.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться для чего вам необходимо создавать так много окон? Почему нельзя каждый раз открывать и закрывать одно и то же окно?

Comment: @Mr.Modest наследование не решит проблему, окно удаляться не будет, если только не знаешь что прописать в Dispose. Задача более широкая чем я написал в теме, объяснять сложно, да и открыть окно которое было закрыто не получиться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Открывать окно в собственном потоке - не очень хорошая идея, обычно в поток выделяют только вычисления. Однако, в данном примере память будет освобождаться, если подписаться на событие `Closed` окна и вызвать [`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeshutdown(v=vs.110).aspx), а после закрытия окна вызвать [`Dispatcher.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run(v=vs.110).aspx). В реальном использовании `Dispatcher.Run` вызывается после открытия окна, а закрытие происходит по действию пользователя, а не программно.

```
private void Something()
{
    var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var w = new Window() { Width = 1024, Height = 768 };
        w.Show();
        w.Closed += (s, ex) => 
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        w.Close();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    });
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
    t.Start();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

[Информация отсюда](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/).

Comment: Тадам! Поясню, это окно ожидание так сказать. Оно просто должно быть в другом потоке. Спасибо за ответ.